# Not able to get result set from stored procedure in ESQL?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am calling external stored procedure from esql., where input is also clob and output also clob.

i have to  send input and and get response from Oracle DB Stored procedure.

but im getting error as **SQL TYPE NOT FOUND 0** Error...

Any suggestions...

#MessageBroker #IIB #ESQL

CALL pro_call(P_DATA_CLOB,P_INIT_LOGGING) INTO V_RETRUN;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_call(IN P_REQUEST CHAR ,IN P_INIT_LOGGING BOOLEAN) 
RETURNS CHAR
LANGUAGE DATABASE 
EXTERNAL NAME "INTERFACE.LPB_SERVICING.GET_SERVICE";
```

have tried this, but getting error response.

Please let us know if any one used this and get success response.

Comment: I believe your error is coming from your external program, not from the database. Double check to make sure your program knows what a Boolean is.

Comment: Are you sure that SQL runs under Oracle? functions return something, not procedures.

Comment: Yes this error is occured in ESQL in IIB toolkit, if we run the function in Oracle DB it is giving results, and its not a procedure, it is function under package

Comment: Can you include the whole IIB exception?

Comment: Sure...

Have tried some methods..

Error :
Text:CHARACTER:The procedure '&1' with '&2' parameters could not be match with a corresponding Database stored porocedure.
Insert
 Type:INTEGER:5
Text:CHARACTER:LPBTEST.INTERFACE.LPB_SERVICING.GET_SERVICE
Insert
 Type:INTEGER:2
 Text:CHARACTER:3
ESQL Code:   
CALL compasscall(P_DATA_CLOB,P_INIT_LOGGING,v_Return);
CREATE PROCEDURE compasscall(IN P_REQUEST CHAR ,IN P_INIT_LOGGING BOOLEAN, OUT v_Return CHAR)LANGUAGE DATABASE EXTERNAL NAME "INTERFACE.LPB_SERVICING.GET_SERVICE";

Comment: Text:CHARACTER:Child SQL exception
           Insert
             Type:INTEGER:5
             Text:CHARACTER:HY000
           Insert
             Type:INTEGER:2
             Text:CHARACTER:0
           Insert
             Type:INTEGER:5
             Text:CHARACTER:[IBM][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]SQL type not supported: 0
             
CREATE PROCEDURE compasscall(IN P_REQUEST CHAR ,IN P_INIT_LOGGING BOOLEAN) RETURNS CHAR
 LANGUAGE DATABASE EXTERNAL NAME "INTERFACE.LPB_SERVICING.GET_SERVICE";
 
 CALL compasscall(P_DATA_CLOB,P_INIT_LOGGING) INTO Pro_Request1;

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the BOOLEAN parameter in your declaration. Oracle SQL doesn't have a BOOLEAN type, so there is no mapping between the ESQL BOOLEAN and an Oracle type.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=functions-data-types-values-from-external-databases

Comment: yes but the oracle function declaration also have the Boolean type as input..

I Have added the function declaration here...

function get_service(p_request clob, p_init_logging boolean := true) return clob;

Comment: Maybe try creating a function that hides the boolean parameter with a type that is supported by IIB.

Comment: I really don't know how to do that, could you please suggest me something...

Comment: I mean you could create a new function in your DB, that have an INTEGER in place of the current BOOLEAN parameter and that new function would be calling the existing function and translating the new INTEGER parameter to a BOOLEAN value. And then you should be able to call the new function from IIB.